# Managing and accessing Terabytes of data

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

A client has approximately 40 TB of data on different hard disks. He wants to create a server, with 40 TB of storage, and move the data to it, which can be accessed by four different users. Eventually he plans on making the songs available for download. What is the best way to handle this? Should I suggest him to go for cloud storage, or getting a in house server better? If I suggest him a server, would a simple windows based server work for him?

Comment: GlusterFS is pretty good for this sort of thing. Might be a bit overkill for just four users, but should be able to manage multi-user access, streaming, backups, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the end goal is to distribute music without permission from the copyright holder

Comment: No it is not to distribute music without permission from the copyright holder. It is for local music, and this is required by a local museum(government owned) in my country. Sorry for not mentioning this before

Comment: @Ramhound That's pretty presumptuous. It could be his own music.

Comment: @Ramhound You know what they say about **ass**uming..

Comment: @MichaelFrank - It might be presumptuous, but 40 TB of his own music, thats like a lifetime of music.  Question could have simply said, 40 TB accross multiple HDDs, wants to create a server with a 40 TB capacity, and allow users to download the data.  Answer would be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the songs become available for download, you will want cloud storage of some kind include a CDN (content distribution network), because you will get a ton of bandwidth for a cheaper price.

Depending on files size upload/download speeds maybe an issue.

Locally, you would need 10  4TB hard drives for data, 2 for RAID 6, and at least 2 for expansion.  You need a hardware RAID 6 controller and at least 14 hard drives.  This means you need a case that can handle that many hard drives plus more for expansion and spares.

RAID 6 will give you the ability to lose 2 drives at once and not lose any of your data.  If you lose 3 hard drives all the data is gone.  However, this is why you need a backup.

Depending on how they want to use the data a simple windows server could be all they need on the software side.